# Set Relative path in file SetUp and Deployment

Tags: .net, deployment, windows-installer, installation

How can the relative file path be set in setup and deployment project. So that if I take the poject to another machine it will build

Comment: +1 because we're about to switch to MSBuild and I'll need to know about this.

Comment: also, are you using msbuild or wix?

Answer (score 0):

You can use clickonce build. It will help out your problem.