# How can I make the SourcePath property of a file in a Visual Studio Setup and Deployment project (Windows Installer) relative rather than absolute?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, windows-installer, installation

I've got a relatively simple project that is under source control (svn), and I wanted to create an installer. I know that I could (should) use [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/index.html), but as I'm new to creating installers I thought it'd be easier to just use the built-in Visual Studio (2010) Setup and Deployment Wizard.

Unfortunately, it seems that files including external (non-project maintained) documentation, configuration files, and ["Content" files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036216/what-are-content-files-in-visual-studio-setup-project-file-system) are added with absolute paths. This, of course, is suboptimal. I searched the web, but found only the [same question](http://www.windowsdevelop.com/clickonce-setup--deployment-projects/sourcepath-in-setup-project-is-always-changed-from-relative-to-absolute-path-16283.shtml), without an answer. Another stackoverflow user seems to have asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950642/set-relative-path-in-file-setup-and-deployment), but the only answer, which suggests [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce), seems off-base (I'd like to have an MSI that I distribute not a web-based installation).

Does anyone know how (or whether) this can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier now but when you start bumping into the limitations of the tool it's going to get real hard.  Let's not even talk about the bad practices it will encourage which could end up being real hard for the poor end user installing your product.   You've got Visual Studio 2010 so InstallShield LE ( free ) would be a better choice.

Otherwise, to answer your question, it will only use absolute paths if it can't caculate a relative path.  (  for example c:\foo\foo.vdproj consuming d:\foo.txt  consuming c:\test\foo.txt should automatically be ....\test\foo.txt )

BTW, if you decide to check out WiX and want some "easy"  check out my IsWiX project on CodePlex.  I'm trying to bridge the feature gap between InstallShield and WiX.

Comment: All the files are on the same drive, within a few branches of a (great-)grandparent directory (i.e., 2x to 3x parent directory). And yet I still get absolute paths for relative paths that should be easy to calculate (e.g., project c:\solution\project_a\project_a.vdproj with added file c:\solution\project_b\ReadMe.txt).

Comment: Sorry, I've never observed that b ehavior.  I've always seen it behave as I described above.  Either way, I wouldn't touch VDPROJ with a 100' pole.  Life is too short.

Comment: I think the confusion here is that it uses the relative path (check out the proj file) and displays the absolute path.

Answer (score 3):

With VS2005, sometimes the paths stored in the vdproj file were absolutes, and sometimes relatives.  In my case, it seemed to be related to whether the files were accessed via the canonical path or not.  Here's a concrete example:

Source is on C:\Views\builddir, open solution C:\Views\builddir\solution.sln and add files from C:\Views\builddir\.. and VS2005 would add **relative** paths into the vdproj file.  However, if you map that builddir to a letter drive, for example, make a subst from C:\Views\builddir to s:, open the solution via S:\solution.sln, and then add files by navigating to S:\.., VS2005 would insert **absolute** paths into the vdproj files.  Whether VS2005 displayed paths as absolutes or relatives had no relation to what it stored in the vdproj files.

So, it may well be that the problem comes down to what path you're using to open that solution.. opening \\server\shareddir\solution.sln might get different behavior than mapping \\server\shareddir to W: and opening w:\solution.sln.

You can always add the files, then use a text editor (e.g. notepad) to change the absolute paths in the vdproj file to relative ones.  You'll be fine until you change that project again.

MS doesn't seem to really fix minor bugs like this so much as rewrite the code to introduce an entirely different set of bugs, so VS2010 might still act this way.

FYI, why would one want to map an absolute path to your builddir?  It was a holdover from the bad old days when VS didn't do anything correct with relative paths.

Answer (score 3):

As tzerb mentioned, the main source of confusion might be that paths show up as absolute under the property window inside VS, but when you look into the actual VDPROJ file you should see the paths show up as relative.  However, as patbob mentioned, I believe the paths ARE stored as absolute when they come from a different letter drive.